# How Change the Style of views based on user option

Tags: views, theming

I have a set of products into grid view. I need to create a two tabs one for grid view and list view(swipe view). How to create like this using views in drupal 7?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like this will need to be done programmatically.

Use hook_views_pre_render() to be able to change the settings of a view based on certain conditions.

https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/7

Then using the global $user definition to lookup the logged in user, use that to create a condition and alter the settings of the actual view.